# How to set http_proxy env variable and have wget using it transparently before login (Debian)

Tags: linux, environment-variables, wget, http-proxy

By setting environment variable http_proxy="http://proxy-server" I'm able to call programs like wget, curl, etc, using the set http proxy transparently. To persist this to the whole system I've added http_proxy to the /etc/environment.

I'm using getty to run a bash script that wraps /bin/login. This script runs a wget and I want it to use the http proxy transparently. The problem is that system-wide http_proxy doesn't exist before login.

I've tried also setting http_proxy on user ~/.profile and running wget using sudo hoping that the user env variable would be used but it didn't work:

```
sudo -i -u user wget http://example.com
# no proxy connection
```

The env variable is available though:

```
sudo -i -u user echo \$http_proxy
# prints http://proxy-server
```

But it's like it is not available to wget.

How can I run wget before login and make it use the previously set http_proxy env variable transparently?

Comment: You set it in the script, or the init definition. Often, init scripts have /etc/defaults/* just for this. For logins, rc might be where you have the first chance to set it.